# Bash script Partition skip if already exists

Tags: bash

I am trying to create partition using the below script. It works, but sometimes I need to re-run the same script due to some automation stuff during the time I am getting error like already in use.

```
parted /dev/sdc --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc1
mkdir -p /opt/app
lsblk
echo "/dev/sdc1    /opt/app    xfs     defaults   0  1"  >>/etc/fstab
mount -a
df -Th
```

Error log when I executing the same script again.

```
+ parted /dev/sdc --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%
Error: Partition(s) on /dev/sdc are being used.
+ mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc1
mkfs.xfs: /dev/sdc1 contains a mounted filesystem
```

How can I skip if the file system from `/dev/sdc` is already mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if [the mount is already there](https://serverfault.com/questions/50585/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-volume-is-mounted-in-a-bash-script), and skip the script if it's found;

```sh
if grep -qs '/dev/sdc' /proc/mounts; then
    echo "Skipping mount since /dev/sdc already exists"
else
    parted /dev/sdc --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%
    mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc1
    mkdir -p /opt/app
    lsblk
    echo "/dev/sdc1    /opt/app    xfs     defaults   0  1"  >>/etc/fstab
    mount -a
    df -Th
fi
```

Comment: sorry its throwing error ./test.sh
Error: Partition(s) on /dev/sdc are being used.
mkfs.xfs: /dev/sdc1 contains a mounted filesystem
Usage: mkfs.xfs

Comment: Looks like the issue is that grep is searching for /dev/sdc[space] and so not picking up /dev/sdc1 changing grep -qs '/dev/sdc  ' to grep -qs '/dev/sdc' should sort it

Comment: I've removed the trailing space, thanks for pointing that out @RamanSailopal. Could you please try again @Anonymuss?

Comment: Glad it worked! Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.